# Retrieve Facebook friends using the app - Swift 3

Tags: swift, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to retrieve a list of the user's Facebook friends that are using the app. To my knowledge, this permission is granted automatically but please do correct me if I'm wrong.

Here is the code I am using to retrieve the list. At the moment it just skips the code in the completion handler without leaving any messages in the console.

```
let params = ["fields": "id, first_name, last_name, name"]
    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/me/friends", parameters: params).start { (connection, result, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print("ERROR: \(error.debugDescription)")
        }
        else {


            if let friendArray : NSArray = (result as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "data") as! NSArray
            {

                for friend in friendArray {
                    print("Name \((friend as AnyObject).value(forKey: "name"))")
                }


            }
        }

    }
```

Unfortunately I can't seem to find any up to date documentation on this topic.